# Call admin controller function using CURL in Magento

Tags: php, magento, curl

I want to call admin Controller action through CURL in Magento. I have written the code for curl but it redirect me on Login page of magento admin panel.

Please let me know if anybody have Idea to how to call it.

Comment: have you looked at `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::preDispatch()`?

Comment: I am planning to call a CURL for background Process.So I guess this wont work.

Comment: there is an event called 'adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start' which you can listen to and check for any curl auth information that will log you in as a certain user - on the other side what action would like to call? Could use soap? or create a simple php script for that?